# Choosing correct lifetime scope for Autofac components in MVC 5, SignlaR, NServiceBus

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, autofac, hangfire

I am trying to understand how to correctly register components and dependencies with Autofac in a MVC 5 application that also uses the following:

1. Application Services (billing service, etc.)
2. Hangfire (there is a Hangfire.Autofac integration package)
3. SignalR (there is a Autofac.SignalR integration package)
4. NServiceBus (there is a NServiceBus.Autofac integration package)
5. Quartz.NET (there is a Quartz.Autofac integration package)
6. Entity Framework (all of the above may or may not need a DbContext injected)

While I understand the purpose of e.g. `builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().InstancePerRequest()` when used as per-request and injected into an MVC controller, I am unclear how the other components need to be registered.

The MVC container I register in OWIN startup.cs class with:

```
var resolver = new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver( container );
DependencyResolver.SetResolver( resolver );
```

I have an extra Autofac container for SignalR, because it would not work otherwise.

**So it all comes down to the question: With what lifetime scope should I register a MyDbContext that is used by a MVC Controller, a SignalR hub, an NServiceBus Message handler, *and* some application service at the same time?**

Is it enough to register `MyDbContext` as `.InstancePerRequest()` or is it neccessary to have multiple containers, and with that, should I register `MyDbContext` with each container?

I am new to Autofac so I'm at a loss as to how I could control when those components are disposed, recreated, etc.

Thank you.